# Regex with grep

Tags: regex, grep, githooks

I want to add a githook which checks that when changes in a file contain a TODO, it should be followed by a ticket number. For example, this is correct `// TODO PK-123456` but this one should match and prevent a commit: `// TODO do it later`.

This is my Regex:

```
\/\/ +TODO (?!PK-[0-9]{6})
```

However when I try to use this (on Mac OS)

```
git diff --cached | grep  -E '\/\/ +TODO (?!PK-[0-9]{6})'
```

I get the following error:

**grep: repetition-operator operand invalid**

Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to escape `/` since it isn't special... anyway, the issue is that grep doesn't support lookarounds and many other features you typically find in programming languages.. if you install GNU grep or ripgrep, you can use `-P` option to enable `PCRE` which does support lookarounds.. see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use another grep then the pre-installed because this has to work on all machines in our team without any additional installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply split the grep into two, while negating the second one with the `-v` flag:

```
git diff --cached | egrep '// +TODO' | egrep -v '// +TODO +PK-[0-9]{6}'
```